# simple script errors at 1) in case statement in a file listing script

Tags: bash, file, case

Couldn't really find a thread similar to this one so I thought I'd make a new thread. I'm trying to make a basic bash script that displays the name of files inside the current directory one at a time.

An echo statement says 'Would you like to preview this file? Y/N', If Yes then the code goes on to display the first 3 lines of that file using the head syntax, the program then exits.

So this is what I had in mind so far,

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./* #This points to current directory with ./* and views files inside.
do
    if [[ -f $file ]] #If File Exists, read it
            read file
    then
            echo -e 'Would you like to view this file? Press 1 For Yes and 2 For No'
            read boolean #reads the prompt 1 or 2 to then proceed with the case              statement below
    case $boolean
    1)
            echo -e 'Preview of File...'
            read boolean
            2)
            echo -e 'Exit Program...'
            read boolean
    if [ boolean -eq 1 ] #This part of the code finds out if the prompt was answered with 1 (yes), if it was then it produces the first 3 lines of the file, if it was 2 then it quits the program.
    then line=$(head -n 3 file)
    else
    *( echo -e 'Please enter a valid option' #If someone enters 3-9 then the program will require them to enter a valid number.
    esac
    done
    fi
```

The program displays an error at line 23 "1)" just after initiating a case statement. Is this not the proper syntax? I'm not quite sure why it would do that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you missed `in`

```
case "$boolean" in
    1)
```

Second, you missed `;;`

```
read boolean ;;
```

Also, quote your variables. It seems like there are other errors as well.

Comment: In particular, the `if ...; then ...; else ...; fi` syntax is badly broken in a couple spots as well...